# Loading google maps js file dynamically causing error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i have this code as the last line in my body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

i tried to load the above script dynamically using

$.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false", function() { mapsloaded(); });

and inside the callback when i try to call

```
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

i get an error, this method is not supported, What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is that the only error? Is the error associated with "mapsloaded" or the constructor "Geocoder"? Just for testing sake, can you add a setTimeout in the callback, like so - and see if the error still shows? Otherwise, can you supply a link? $.getScript("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js??sensor=false", function() { 
    setTimeout(function(){mapsloaded(); },2000);
}); => I am assuming mapsloaded is defined somewhere.

Comment: Same problem here with no resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647233/jquery-getscript-not-working-properly-with-google-maps-api